# How to set Height as Auto in a DataGridView in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I'm dealing right now with this situation. As you know, in `WPF` you can set your controls as Auto its size *(Width or Height)*, so when you do this, the controls does not appear its vertical scroll-bar.

I want the same behavior in one `DataGridView` in Windows Forms, this control has many rows and I want to know that the control express its real size without vertical scroll-bars. How can I do this feature?

[image]

By the moment, the `DataGridView` has a fixed size (600px)

Comment: I don't think the WPF DataGrid can adjust to its contents. You can adjust the content (Column Widths mainly) to the Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your initial height is set such that scrollbars are not visible, adding these event handlers will allow your height to scale when rows are added or removed:

```
private void dataGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = e.RowIndex; i < (e.RowIndex + e.RowCount); i++)
        height += dataGridView.Rows[i].Height;

    dataGridView.Height += height;
}    

private void dataGridView_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = e.RowIndex; i < (e.RowIndex + e.RowCount); i++)
        height += dataGridView.Rows[i].Height;

    dataGridView.Height -= height;
}
```

As a side-note, I would recommend *not* employing this functionality in your program.  Automatically-resizing listboxes are generally a poor UI design choice.  What are you trying to accomplish with this control?  There may be a more effective method for doing what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I'm showing several DataGridViews in a TableLayoutContainer, I'm trying use just one vertical scrollbar (thil will have the table) and for that all the datagridviews should have it real Height without scrollbars

Comment: You might wish to consider fixing the height of the DataGridViews, but hiding the scrollbars (`dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None`).  You can then trap the events from an external scrollbar and use them to scroll multiple DataGridViews at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set its `Dock` property. Assuming it's called as follows:

```
dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
```

Clearly, the grid will still show scrollbars, but its height will be adapted to its container's.